# Lubuntu frozen while installing

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, lubuntu, freeze

I have this old PC hanging around so I decided to install Lubuntu on it just to give it some life and it freezes every time. I made a bootable USB, made two partitions (an ext4 and a swap partition) and whenever I reach the "Who are you?" page, where I input my name and password and click "Continue", the mouse freezes and I'm unable to do anything. I've tried it twice now, each time I had to remake the bootable USB because it wouldn't boot again.
Any ideas?
The computer is pretty old but it has 1Gb of RAM, 256MB dedicated graphics and a 2,00Ghz Intel Pentium Processor.

Comment: How did you create the USB media? Have you tried a different drive?

Comment: Using the last version Universal USB Installer. I don't have any other drive I could use right now, could that be the problem?

Comment: It could be, but I think the problem is because you're using that program. Try out [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) and see if that helps.

Comment: All right man, gonna give it a shot and report when done.

Comment: I think it fixed it!! If went past the screen it used to freeze in and it's currently copying files! You're the man!

Comment: Great! I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen a lot of other people who have problems with Universal USB Installer. For some reason, it just doesn't seem to like Ubuntu.

Instead, since you're on Windows, use [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie). It's portable, it's free, it's small and, most importantly, it works really well.